# PHP initiate download, then wait a few seconds and delete file. How to avoid client side wait before opening file?

Tags: php, download

In a PHP aplication, the user can click on a button to initiate the download of a file just created for him. The file will no longer be needed, once downloaded. So, after sending the file (via header(), see below), the PHP script waits a few seconds, then deletes the file.

While this is working on the server side, the client side application (if "open with" was chosen) is only launched **after** that couple of seconds have passed by.

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=QR-Rechnung.pdf");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($FilePathName));
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control:  private", false);
header("Connection: close");

readfile($FilePathName);

sleep(20);
unlink($FilePathName);
```

My guess would be the client side operating system (Windows) waits for the connection to be closed, before launching the target application.

It seems `header("Connection: close");` is not sufficient. I also tried with `ob_flush()` and `ob_end_flush`, but neiher helped.

I'm looking for a solution *without* JavaScript, since I want the file to get deleted even when JavaScript is disabled on the client.

Comment: `waits for the connection to be closed`...not really. More that php waits until the whole script has completed before sending the data to the browser.

Comment: What you probably need is actually a cron job to periodically clear out such temporary files from your server. Trying to do it in the same script where it's being offered for download isn't really practical

Comment: The only real good method that I can see is to periodically run a batch that deletes older files (e.g. via cron)

Comment: Is the sleeping part really necessary? I never heard that readfile would be "blocking" in that regard, so that you could not delete the file immediately after readfile was done. Is that an issue you are trying to work around here with that, or ...?

Comment: @CBroe The intention was to give the customer a second chance, should he inadvertantly abort the first download. Though I could avoid a separate cron job, but will got for it now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay, that kinda makes sense - although on the other hand then again it rather doesn't, because those 20 seconds are a "magic number", pulled out of thin air - you can't possibly know how long it will take the user, to realize their "mistake" in that regard. So you're probably better off here, if you leave cleanup after a larger amount of time has passed, to a cron job. If the data really _needs_ to be written to a file beforehand to begin with, that is [...]

Comment: [...] (because the part that creates it, is beyond your control or ability to modify, or assembling the data takes so long/ "costs" so much, that you'd rather not do it a second time, in that rather unlikely/ rare scenario of inadvertantly aborted download) - if that's not the case, creating and echo-ing the data on the fly, might make more sense.

Comment: @CBroe In the first place, the code initated the download directly. But that left the cutomer with the former HTML page (a form with data he entered) and that looked ugly to me. So I decide to separate creation and download. I have now changed the code to delete immediately, and inform the customer re-ordering is due, if the file was no longer found. Not 100% happy with this solution, but I'll have to postpone a redesign of that part; no time at the moment.